# Retrieve values for select box from database at login page

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I have created a login form. It include the Customer Name,Username,Password. Customer Name is list of different customers. I have to update the list from database. Can anyone help to solve this issue. Thanks.
My html code for login page is,

```
<div id="divcust" class="form-group">
            <select class="form-control" id="customerlist" placeholder="Customer Name" autofocus required>
                <option value="">Select Customer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
  <div id="divusr" class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="text" id="txtUid" name="username" data-validation="alphanumeric" class="form-control" placeholder="UserName" tabindex="1"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user form-control-feedback"></span> </div>
  <div id="divpwd" class="form-group has-feedback">
    <input type="password" id="txtPwd" name="password" data-validation="length" data-validation-length="min5" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" tabindex="2"/>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock form-control-feedback"></span> </div>
                <div id="divtc"class="form-group has-feedback" >
                    <input type="checkbox" id="cbtnc" name="check" data-validation="required" data-validation-error-msg="You have to agree to our Terms and Conditions to access" class="minimal" tabindex="3"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I accept the <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#terms-conditions-modal-info">Terms and Conditions</a> of access.
                    <span class="glyphicon form-control-feedback"></span>
                </div>
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-xs-offset-8 col-xs-4">
                        <button type="button" id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" onclick="verifyLogin();" tabindex="4">Sign In</button>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used `jQuery` to use `$.ajax()` method.

My JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m6vrfmw1/2/

> To use `jQuery` in your project, add `<script
>   src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`
>   into your `<head>` tag.

---

Inside the `$.ajax()` method, I used `$.each()` method to iterate over the `JSON` data and append them into the `<select>` tag.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/clwcxTNthK?indent=2", // URL to fetch data from DB
  success: function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
      $("#customerlist").append('<option value="[Add Custom Value Here]">' + item.name + '</option>');
    });
  }
});
```